# Asyncio with pyhon3 await error when using the update function for kasa

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am using the Kasa smart plug library. However, when i run

```
asyncio.run(self.device.update())
```

I get an error

> kasa.exceptions.SmartDeviceException: You need to await update() to access the data

Therefore, I changed my code to

```
await asyncio.run(self.device.update())
```

However, this hasn't helped. Any help is appreciated

This is my code

```
import asyncio
from kasa import SmartPlug


class TpLinkHandler():
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.device = SmartPlug(address)
        self.details = self.device.hw_info

    def update(self):
        await asyncio.run(self.device.update())

    def shutdown(self):
        asyncio.run(self.device.turn_off())
        return "shutdown"

    def turnOn(self):
        asyncio.run(self.device.turn_on())
        return "Turning on"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.details

if __name__ == "__main__":
    device = TpLinkHandler("192.168.0.41")
    device.update()
    device.turnOn()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this error you need to change the update function to

```
    async def update(self):
        await self.device.update()
```

Comment: This change alone isn’t sufficient since it changes how `update` would need to be called.

Comment: Correct, it needs to be called when an async task is already in operation